# Copy an attribute from one element to another with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code which doesn't seem to be doing anything. When the link is clicked, I'm trying to get the value of its `url` attribute to be copied into the `iframe`'s `src` attribute.

Basically this is supposed to make links open up in an iframe (the content of the iframe is replaced every time a new link is clicked) instead of acting like normal links.

So what is wrong with my code?

```
$('p.tweet a').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('url');
    $('iframe').attr('src',link);
})
```

Comment: What's the `url` attribute? You meant `href`, presumably..? And, incidentally, `var link = this.href;` works just as well and slightly more quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what is wrong with my code?

You are not canceling the default action by returning false from the click handler of the anchor you subscribed to and thus not leaving any chance for your script to execute before the browser simply redirects away from that page:

```
$('p.tweet a').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('iframe').attr('src', link);
    return false;
});
```

And by the way notice that I've used `$(this).attr('href')` instead of `$(this).attr('url')`. The `href` attribute is kinda more common to anchors than the `url` attribute in standard HTML, but if you have invented some markup in which anchors have an `url` attribute then you could give it a spin.

Comment: this came in handy today. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 5):

maybe you may want to get the `href` attribute (and even prevent the default action)

```
$('p.tweet a').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var link = this.href;  // no need to call the $ function
    $('iframe').attr('src',link);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL of a hyperlink is contained in the `href` attribute, not the `url` attribute.

You should also prevent the default action, making your code look like this:

```
$('p.tweet a').click(function(event){
    var link = $(this).attr('url');
    $('iframe').attr('src',link);
    // cancel default event
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I know, I'm storing the value in a fake attribute until it can be copied over to the iframe

Comment: You may want to use a `data-` tag and the `data()` function. `$(this).data('url');`

Comment: @SamNabi - So I assume the issue was not cancelling the default event and you're all set, then (updated answer, although it's not very useful since there are already two answers saying the say thing)? Also, dcpomero is correct -- adding a custom attribute without the `data-` prefix is invalid HTML (it will still work correctly though, so it's not a huge issue).